# Google AppEngine Data Store - Log in remotely?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosql

Is there a way to log in to my AppEngine app's Data Store remotely, in order to insert and modify entities? Or can I only do it in the server-side code that I deploy on AppEngine?

I'm trying to generate a database on AppEngine from publicly available data online, and I would like to run a program locally that makes these inserts on my AppEngine database. Is this possible? Or do I have to deploy a servlet on AppEngine that does this for me?

I guess the question boils down to whether Google AppEngine's Data Stores can be accessed remotely (by the outside world) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

See the remote API:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

Just be very wary as you must include your admin credentials in source code.